# Regular expression to get upto second word

Tags: regex, oracle

In

```
SELECT '5-CULVERTS AND UNDERPASSES' FROM DUAL;
```

trying to get `5-CULVERTS AND` with query string upto second word

trying this

```
select regexp_substr('5-CULVERTS AND UNDERPASSES','[^ ]{2}+') from dual
```

but no help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match the two first words, you can do this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(mycolumn, '\S+\s+\S+', 1, 1, 'cm') FROM dual;
```

**Explanation**

- `\S+` matches any characters that are not space characters (the first word)
- `\s+` matches any space chars
- `\S+` matches the second word

**Option 2: Second Word is Optional**

Use this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('6-BRIDGES', '\S+(\s+\S+)?', 1, 1) FROM dual;
```

The spaces and second word are now in parentheses, and made optional by the `?`

Comment: Oh right. I forgot about the `\S` instead of `[^\s]`. But I won't change my answer because you have done `\S`. +1 to you

Comment: @sshashank124 Thanks, nearly identical answers, I'll take care of you next time. :)

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('6-BRIDGES', '\S+\s+\S+', 1, 1) FROM dual;` this returning null

Comment: Yes, you said you want two words. If you want 1 OR two words, use this: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('6-BRIDGES', '\S+(\s+\S+)?', 1, 1) FROM dual;` Will update the answer. :)

Comment: Updated answer, let me know if that does it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows:

```
[^\s]+\s[^\s]+
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/yQ7fZ2)

```
select regexp_substr('5-CULVERTS AND UNDERPASSES','[^\s]+\s[^\s]+') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way

> SQL> select regexp_substr('5-CULVERTS AND
>   UNDERPASSES','**\S+(\s+\S+)?**',1,1) from dual;

### Out put

5-CULVERTS AND